# How to use localization with RubyMotion?

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby, localization, rubymotion

I think it's not possible to use [I18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n), so what's the best approach?

From what I see you can use [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap) as so:

```
# Localization (using NSBundle.mainBundle.localizedStringForKey):
BubbleWrap.localized_string(:foo, 'fallback')
=> "fallback"
```

But there is no explanations on how to setup the translation keys and is [just a mapping of](https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap/blob/master/motion/core.rb#L15):

```
NSBundle.mainBundle.localizedStringForKey(key, value:value, table:nil)
```

... so I'm not sure what to do with it.

Bubblewrap also provides a `App.current_locale` method, but this returns an object that seems unusable as far as I can understand.

**So, how can I localize my RubyMotion application, or at least get the user's locale to create my own localization system.**

Answer (score 2):

RubyMotion use CocoaTouch API. You can check apple documentation on localization https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html

Answer (score 1):

The way to use it is beatifully explained in [colinta's blogpost](http://colinta.com/thoughts/rubymotion_i18n.html).

There's also [GitHub gist by chsh](https://gist.github.com/chsh/2651921) that shows a reasonable example.

But to answer in detail:

Create `resources/en.lproj/Localizable.strings` with content:

```
/* This is a sample greeting for my app */
"GREETING" = "Hello World!";
```

(and similarly for other languages: `cs.lproj`, `de.lproj`, ...).

Then you can use [sugarcube's localized](https://github.com/rubymotion/sugarcube#localized) support: `"HELLO"._` which will result in `"Hello World!"` for `en` locale and `GREETING` for any locale with corresponding `lproj` file missing. You can find more detail in sugarcube's docs linked above.

You could most likely also use the [BubbleWrap's localized_string](https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap#misc) support: `BW.localized_string("GREETING", "fallback")`. I can't vouch for it as I haven't tested it myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

I18n is now available to Rubymotion with this wrapper gem: [motion-i18n](https://github.com/tkadauke/motion-i18n).

Answer (score -2):

We have just released [motion-phrase](https://github.com/phrase/motion-phrase) a gem for RubyMotion that implements a [localization workflow using PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com). It is a quite different approach but comes with a lot of advantages.